# fieldChanged() method not called when "field.property" is changed from child component

Tags: javascript, observable, aurelia

This is my parent view model and view.

```js
export class Parent {
  @observable field;

  fieldChanged() {
    console.log('field has been changed');
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <child-component field.two-way="field" />
</template>
```

When I do

```
this.field.property = 'new value';
```

in child-component, **fieldChanged** method is not called.

Note that field is type of **object**. With primitive types it works well.
Can I do something to make this work on object types?

Comment: It works when I test it, are you sure you're updating the right variable in your `field = 'new value';`? I'd think you need to update `this.field`

Comment: Components are void elements. They are not self-closing. `<child-component field.two-way="field"></child-component>`. So probably the line `field='new value';` doesn't run at all.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer Actually, I just tested it with a `<child field.two-way="field" />` and the `fieldChanged` still fires (the child component is visible as well). The only problem is that any HTML afterwards is invalid ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to observe a property of an object, you can use the [`bindingEngine`](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/how-to-observe-objects-in-aurelia-using-the-binding-engine/23):

```
import { BindingEngine, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class Parent {
  field = {
    property: ''
  }

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  attached() {
    this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this.field, 'property')
      .subscribe((newValue, oldValue) => {
      // do your logic here
    })
  }

  detached() {
    // Dispose subscription to avoid memory leak
    this.subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to `dispose` the observer on `detached` to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Any reason for doing this in the `attached` lifecycle method and not earlier, like in `bind` or even the `constructor`?

Comment: So I need to do this for each property I want to observe. And if it is nested deeper then it will be harder.

Comment: @MartinPach yes you do, and deeper nesting doesn't make it much harder, you'd just need `propertyObserver(this.field.field.field, 'property')`

Comment: @pavsaund not really, just a convention for me. I reckon you could do this in any of the cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BindingEngine.expressionObserver` method to observe a path, instead of a single property

```
const observer = bindingEngine
  .expressionObserver(this /* or any object */, 'field.property')
  .subscribe(newValue => console.log('new field.property is:', newValue))
```

And remember to call `observer.dispose()` later when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

you probably didn't declare the binding in the child component:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ChildComponent
{
    @bindable field;

   /* DO whatever you want*/
}
```

btw:
in your code you should have `this.field = 'new value';` and not `field = 'new value';`

Comment: I found out what is the problem. The problem is that my 'field' is type of object (I will update description) no primitive type. With primitive types it works fine, however with objects not. Is there any way to observe an object?

Comment: you can [observe object mutation](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/how-to-observe-objects-in-aurelia-using-the-binding-engine/23), but its a little bit harder.